# Exibir imagem padrão, caso não exista no banco de dados

Tags: php

Fiz uma condição para que quando não houver uma imagem no meu banco de dados, retornar uma imagem padrão, porém, estou tendo um pequeno problema em minha sintaxe e não consegui encontrar uma solução até o momento.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo passar minha variável `$user['photo'];` dentro do meu echo

```
if(!empty($imagem_de_perfil) == null) {
   echo '<img src="../../painel/public/images/no_image.png" alt="Imagem de perfil" width="160" height="120">';
} else {
   echo '<div style="background: url(<?= base_url() ?><?= $user['photo'] ?>); position: relative; left: 48%; background-size: 48px 48px; width: 48px; height: 48px;" class="upload_photo upload_photo_user">
  </div>';
}
```

[image: Erro que aparece ao concatenar]

Comment: O problema é o `'` que você inicia a string e está quebrando no meio dela.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que assim resolveria. O problema é que vc precisar fazer o *escape* das aspas e também fazer a concatenação da string com a função que você chamou e com o `$user["photo"]`

```php
if (!empty($imagem_de_perfil)) {
  echo '<img src="../../painel/public/images/no_image.png" alt="Imagem de perfil" width="160" height="120">';
} else {
  echo '<div style="background: url(\'' . base_url() . $user['photo'] . '\'); position: relative; left: 48%; background-size: 48px 48px; width: 48px; height: 48px;" class="upload_photo upload_photo_user">
    </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro está nessa linha

```
   echo '<div style="background: url(<?= base_url() ?><?= $user['photo'] ?>); position: relative; left: 48%; background-size: 48px 48px; width: 48px; height: 48px;" class="upload_photo upload_photo_user">';
```

Você já declarou `<?php` lá em cima, você só usaria `<?= $user['photo'] ?>` se você estivesse no meio do HTML fora do PHP.

O correto é concatenar variável com a string, ficando assim:

```
echo '<div style="background: url(\''. base_url(). $user['photo'] .'\'); position: relative; left: 48%; background-size: 48px 48px; width: 48px; height: 48px;" class="upload_photo upload_photo_user"> </div>';
```

Outro ponto, se você quiser usar uma variável dentro de uma string, você deve usar aspas dupla, quando você usa aspas simples, você precisa concatenar.

```
echo " Essa é minha variavel $variavel "; //FUNCIONA

echo ' Essa é minha variavel $variavel '; // NÃO FUNCIONA

echo ' Essa é minha variavel '. $variavel; //FUNCIONA
```